# Will a pointless semicolon have any performance impact?

Tags: c#, performance

Sometimes, I notice I add an additional `;` after a statement.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("meow");;
```

Will that effect the performance in my app? Specifically, I am wondering about C#.

Comment: Outside of leaving you scratching your head when you look at the code several years down the road, wondering what you accidentally deleted back then, I rather doubt it.

Comment: No (fifteen characters)

Comment: If you have a performance question the best way to answer it is *try it and see*. Write your program both ways, measure the performance both ways, and see if there is any statistically significant difference between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None whatsoever; it will not impact the IL code that the compiler generates.

It may however have a performance impact on any coworkers who have to maintain your code...

You might be interested in reading about [empty statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), such as

```
bool ProcessMessage() {...}
void ProcessMessages() {
   while (ProcessMessage())
      ;
}
```

Comment: I would say to the OP that empty blocks are more readable in all the cases listed on the link, e.g. `while(ProcessMessages()){/*nothing*/}` but whatever you choose, comments are good too to help it being overlooked by maintaining coworkers.

Answer (score 9):

No, it is ignored as it doesn't get compiled into any IL.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Consider that the colon is a *syntactic* characteristic of the language. The compiler reads your code, analyzes it based on the syntax it knows and figures the *semantics* (the meaning) of your code, organizing them into a structure (typically a tree called AST). *This* is what gets turned to appropriate representations in the target language (assembly, bytecode, other language) from there on - not the format of your code.

An extra semicolon does not denote an extra instruction, it's merely syntactic noise, so it doesn't even make it to the compiler's model of your program. As you can understand from this, the same can be said for such things as extra whitespaces, excessive newlines, etc.

There are, however, conventions in every language that make code more readable to humans who are familiar with that language. It's better to respect them, even if there's no semantic error and no performance penalty for ignoring them. In this case, an extra semicolon would indeed baffle another reader.