# Why C# allow this fun? ; ; ; ;

Tags: c#, syntax

see my below code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExistsOnPath("efsui.exe"); ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
    install(); ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
}
```

I have add more semicolon symbol in visual studio. Why visual studio allowed this? Is it wrong or correct?

See this image and red mark. build is succeeded

[image]

But error shows in this line ?

```
webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.who.int/inf-new/dnldtxt/introductions.zip", "";;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;);
```

[image]

Another fun, the below line is succeeded

```
private void install()
    {
        http://www.stackoverflow.com
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Please be aware of what you are currently using. It is not "Visual Studio" allowing that syntax or not, it is the language C#.

Comment: `;` is a statement terminator, and empty statements are allowed. Empty statements are needed for things like `for(;;)`.

Comment: [Empty Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: ... and also of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762201/why-are-multiple-semicolons-allowed), kind of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465525/will-a-pointless-semicolon-have-any-performance-impact), ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790771/does-c-sharp-allow-double-semicolon-if-so-are-there-any-special-ways

Comment: O.R. yup its' visual studio 2012

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Empty Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374569/c-sharp-empty-statement)

Comment: @RameshRajendran: No, it is not. You could try the same in any other text editor; the code will still compile - because the code is **not compiled by Visual Studio**, it is compiled by the C# compiler based on the C# language specification.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper. Sound nice. But it's does not reutrn any error . buid succeded

Comment: Please See one more time my question

Comment: And just for fun. [This](http://pastebin.com/p68RKXNy) will also compile :)

Comment: @L.B - Yup , That's always run.

Comment: Please look another fun : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559823/c-sharp-code-allow-fun-syntax-and-also-void-method-can-allowed-return

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because semicolon `;` is a valid **Empty Statement**

[8.3 The empty statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> An empty-statement does nothing.
>
> empty-statement:
>
> ;
>
> An empty statement is used when there are no operations to perform in
>   a context where a statement is required.
>
> Execution of an empty statement simply transfers control to the end
>   point of the statement. Thus, the end point of an empty statement is
>   reachable if the empty statement is reachable.

Also see: [Statements (C# Programming Guide) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx)

> The empty statement consists of a single semicolon. It does nothing
>   and can be used in places where a statement is required but no action
>   needs to be performed.

EDIT:

```
webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.who.int/inf-new/dnldtxt/introductions.zip", ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"");
```

> But Why error shows in this line ?

well `;` *semicolon* is a valid empty statement but that doesn't mean that you can place that anywhere in your code. `DownloadFile` method expects two parameters , would you place any statement in it like:

```
webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.who.int/inf-new/dnldtxt/introductions.zip",
                                             Console.Write("Some Text");,  "");
```

Where `Console.Write` is a valid statement itself, but it can't be used for parameter.

> Why this code compiles:

```
private void install()
{
    http://www.stackoverflow.com
    return;
}
```

Because it is treating `http:`  as a [Labeled statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and anything after the colon is considered as part of label text. The above code will produce a warning

> This label has not been referenced

Comment: +1 for Good answer with nice explanation.

Comment: Darn, wrote the same answer, and by the time I was finished typing, there were already 4 answers posted!

Comment: Please See one more time my question

Comment: @RameshRajendran, just updated my answer with your usage of empty statement in a method parameter.

Comment: That's right. hmm good

Comment: and this is always run `private void install()
    {
    http://www.stackoverflow.com
        return;
    }`

Comment: @RameshRajendran, for your edited question, I just updated my answer. The reason it is compiling is because it is treating `http:` as label. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664740(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @RameshRajendran and you take make comment seriously and posted as another question? :)

Comment: Please look another fun : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559823/c-sharp-code-allow-fun-syntax-and-also-void-method-can-allowed-return

Answer (score 3):

The `;` can be used as an empty statement in the C# language.  Hence having many `;` in a row is just fine because it's just a series of empty statements.  Basically a no-op

Note that this is not Visual Studio behavior but instead C# language behavior.  The same code in other languages like VB.Net would produce a compilation error

Answer (score 2):

It succeeds because each statement that ends with a semi-colon doesn't have any syntax errors; they are empty. Now, as far as the generated code, nothing would get generated for those statements.

To better understand it you'd probably want to research how parsers work.