# C# code allow fun syntax, and also void method can allowed return

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax, return

Hi All yesterday i was post one question : like c# allow ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ([C# Empty Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374569/c-sharp-empty-statement))

[Why C# allow this fun? ; ; ; ;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551921/why-c-sharp-allow-this-fun)

and found the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20551989/2218635

But today i saw another one fun(bug)

See this below image

[image]

Why visual studio allow this? Code build success. Why it's build?

and another one fun code always run

```
private void install()
    {
        http://www.stackoverflow.com
        return;
    }
```

**Edit** :

> See above method is a void method , I know void method does not return . But Why it's not shown any error? and I did't assign any variable for the"http://www.stackoverflow.com".but why it's not give me a error ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method builds because it's perfectly valid C#.

Those are labels. They are part of the [`goto`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx) construct that C# inherited from C / C++ that allows execution to jump to a specific point within the method. It's use is generally discouraged.

From [8.4 Labeled statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> A *labeled-statement* permits a statement to be prefixed by a label. Labeled statements are permitted in blocks, but are not permitted as embedded statements.
>
> *labeled-statement*:
>
> *identifier*   :   *statement*
>
> A labeled statement declares a label with the name given by the *identifier*. The scope of a label is the whole block in which the label is declared, including any nested blocks. It is a compile-time error for two labels with the same name to have overlapping scopes.

**Further Reading**

- [Does anyone still use [goto] in C# and if so why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545720/does-anyone-still-use-goto-in-c-sharp-and-if-so-why)

---

Regarding the updated question. Notice that there is no value supplied in the `return` statement. It's perfectly valid to use `return` in this way within a `void` method. That simply causes execution to stop and the control to be transferred back the caller. In fact, you can think of every method having an implicit return statement at then end to return control back to the caller.

It ***would*** be an error if you attempted to return a specific value:

```
return 0;
```

Produces the error:

> Since 'MyPage.Page_Load' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: Why the second fun is successfully build?

Comment: Yup, That's good , but I did't assign any variable for the"http://www.stackoverflow.com".but why it's not give me a error

Comment: @RameshRajendran There's no variable in your function at all. `http:` is a label `//stackoverflow.com` is a comment. Both are perfectly valid elements of C# syntax, but they are not related to variables, and in this case, they don't do anything in your method.